# How to get non-minified react errors for Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Trying to run `gatsby build` and getting this error message.

> failed We've encountered an error: Minified React error #31; visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bid%2C%20frontmatter%2C%20parent%7D](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bid%2C%20frontmatter%2C%20parent%7D) for the full
> message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

To see the full message I have tried:
`"GATSBY_ENV=development && gatsby build --no-uglify"`
But this makes no changes.

Message at reactjs.org

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, frontmatter, parent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Many objects in this project have these keys so I have no way of finding where the problem is.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Gatsby error but React.

If you don't have a clue where the issue is, imagine us. Normally, this kind of errors are related in the way you are trying to render an object instead of a property os this object, typically in loops. For example:

```
const users= [
  {name: 'User 1', surname: 'Surname 1'},
  {name: 'User 2', surname: 'Surname 2'},
  {name: 'User 3', surname: 'Surname 3'},
]

users.map(user => {
   return `the user is ${user}`
})
```

The snippet above will throw the same exception than you've described because `user` is an object which React can't infer nor render. You should do something like:

```
const users= [
  {name: 'User 1', surname: 'Surname 1'},
  {name: 'User 2', surname: 'Surname 2'},
  {name: 'User 3', surname: 'Surname 3'},
]

users.map(user => {
   return `the user name is ${user.name}`
})
```

This snippet is valid because `user.name` is a valid return type (string), not an object.

Comment: Is there any way to trace where the error is happening? And also, why would this work for ```gatsby develop``` but not ```gatsby build```?

Comment: It shouldn't work in `gatsby develop` either (it may not break your compilation but it should show something in the console). Regarding the traceability, in the minified file it's difficult. Try checking the warnings in `gatsby develop`

Comment: Using ```gatsby develop``` and checking every page for console errors helped in the end!